# Variating the derivative of the metric using xTensor

Tags: tensors, variational-calculus, xact

I would like Mathematica to be able to use the following expression in a more complicated computation:
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\frac{\delta{}g^{\alpha\beta}_{\;{},\gamma}\left(x\right)}{\delta{}g^{\mu\nu}\left(x_{1}\right)}=\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta^{\alpha}_{\mu}\delta^{\beta}_{\nu}+\delta^{\alpha}_{\nu}\delta^{\beta}_{\mu}\right)\delta\left(x-x_{1}\right)\right]_{,\gamma}\label{derivative}
\end{equation}
I am currently using the xTensor package and the VarD command.
Ideally I would like to be able to implement the following rule:

```
       metricg /: VarD[var1[m1, n1], PD][PD[-c][metricg[a, b]], rest_] := 
       PD[-c][VarD[metricg[m1, n1]][metricg[a, b]] deltaXX1]*rest
```

As of now this doesn't work, because the "tag metricg is too deep for an assigned rule to be found".

The only workaround I could come up with was to define a new tensor $\Omega^{\alpha\beta}_{\;{},\gamma}:=g^{\alpha\beta}_{\;{},\gamma}$ and implement the rule for it:

```
  Ω /: 
   VarD[var1[m1, n1], PD][Ω[a_, b_, -c_], rest_] := 
   PD[-c][VarD[metricg[m1, n1]][metricg[a, b]] deltaXX1]*rest
```

This works, but substituting back $\Omega$ with the derivative of the metric was cumbersome and I would really like to find a more elegant and transparent solution, that allows me for example not to introduce the tensor $\Omega$ or that uses a better suited Mathematica function (rather than VarD) for computing $(1)$ directly.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!